# Draw countdown circles

Tags: iphone, drawing, geometry

I would like to draw, in a ViewController, a countdown like in the following image:

[image: countdown]

Unfortunately, I don't have any idea on how to realize this. I will be please if someone could give me a clue on this.

Cheers.

Cyril

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick thought, I would not like to draw it by using any iOS frameworks :), Just use small `UIWebView` and run javascript(Only works if user enables javascript, but hey I have seen no one yet who doesn't use javascript).

Javascript polar time can be found on internet, open source like,

http://oneorangesoftware.com/polartimer/

change and edit a bit and off you go! Awesome time!

Cheers!

If you don't like above approach than you may look into this code,

http://www.herbert-siojo.com/2011/04/19/drawing-a-countdown-timer-ios/

nicely crafted however to achieve same look as yours you may have to tweak a bit!

Beware of this line in code,

```
[self performSelector:@selector(cancelPie:) withObject:timer afterDelay:sliderIntervalDelay.value];
```

just change to,

```
[self performSelector:@selector(cancelPie:) withObject:timer afterDelay:60.0];
```

**Credit** : Goes to a developer who posted their code on http://www.herbert-siojo.com/2011/04/19/drawing-a-countdown-timer-ios/.

Comment: I was not satisfied with your first answer so I started to use my brain and developed this with CGContext like in the tuto by myself. Great resource, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

LOL, I am considering to write one like this these days.
You would definitely like this.  :]

Check it out here: [Circle-Counter-Down](https://github.com/pppoe/Circle-Counter-Down)

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: +1, @Cyril, My answer is good but mr.pppoe's answer if awesomely great!!! To mr.pppoe : did you just write this from scratch after reading this question?

Comment: Right! Cyril's screenshot looks great, so I just had a try. :]