# Count Down timer Circle for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I need an open source countdown timer for iPhone as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895244/how-to-use-coreanimation-to-animate-a-circle-like-a-clock-countdown) but in this link only images are shown no source code is provided.

Comment: try the answer given by nico

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu I am searching the code for count down timer, I have tried the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263430/draw-countdown-circles

Comment: @pradeepa Nico Code not working .....it looks the solution to specific problem posted

Comment: @occulus, Jennis, Rais Alam, Tyler, Crompton, Jesus Ramos
please see it now....

Comment: @jennis.... please see it now

Comment: @Rais Alam please see it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this open source project at GitHub

[DACircularProgress](https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress/tree/master/DACircularProgress)

add it to your project, initialize an instance - add it to your view and use the `- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress animated:(BOOL)animated` method to animate to a given value.